# how to not refresh hikaricp from spring boot actuator?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When spring boot actuator refresh, throws exception.

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: The configuration of the pool is sealed once started. Use HikariConfigMXBean for runtime changes.`

changed Hikaricp config, reference `https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/363`

```
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource")
@RefreshScope // added
public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}
```

I want to not refresh hikaricp.
Is there a way?

my environment: spring boot 2.0.4

thanks.

Comment: Remove `@Refresh`.

Comment: occur exception if remove annotation

Comment: Is there a reason you added this bean instead of using the regular `spring.datasource` properties and thus the default datasource?

Comment: I am also getting the same error